# How I use both $ and @ in string?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

```
                    var request = new GraphQLRequest
                {
                    Query = @"
mutation {
  login(email: "{email}", password: "{password}") {
    userId,
    accessToken
  }
}"
                };
```

I am coding with GraphQL with C#

I want to insert "{email}" and "{password}" in string, But above code is not work properly :(

How I solve this..? Please help me

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `@` and `$`, like this: `$@"Hi {username}!"`

```
var somevalue = "your value";
//note: SO's code formatting is a bit off here
var str = $@"Hi
    This is, {somevalue} 
    and more";
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovvje5).

*Note: the order, `$@` is crucial.*

Comment: Bummer.... obvious duplicate